# Каждая кнопка как новый контроллер

Tags: ios, swift4

Как можно сделать, чтобы от каждой кнопки с днем недели, далее был как новый контролер? Человек будет выбирать допустим понедельник и вписывать туда данные, и как сделать чтобы при выборе вторника дальше была пустая графа, а не веденные данные в понедельнике?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showTeacherLessons" {
         let destinationVC = segue.destination as? TeacherWeeks
        //{
        //    destinationVC.lessons = sender as! String
       // }
    }
}

 enum DaysOfWeek: Int {
    case UpMonday = 11
    case UpTuesday = 12
    case UpWednesday = 13
    case UpThursday = 14
    case UpFriday = 15
    case downMonday = 16
    case downTuesday = 17
    case downWednesday = 18
    case downThursday = 19
    case downFriday = 20

    var stringRepresentation: String {
        switch self {
        case .UpMonday:
            return "ПН"
        case .UpTuesday:
            return "ВТ"
        case .UpWednesday:
            return "СР"
        case .UpThursday:
            return "ЧТ"
        case .UpFriday:
            return "ПТ"
            //Down week

        case .downMonday:
            return "ПН"
        case .downTuesday:
            return "ВТ"
        case .downWednesday:
            return "СР"
        case .downThursday:
            return "ЧТ"
        case .downFriday:
            return "ПТ"
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func weeksButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let day = DaysOfWeek.init(rawValue: sender.tag) else { return }
    switch day {
    case .UpMonday:
        let mondayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: mondayTable)
        break
    case .UpTuesday:
        let tuesdayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: tuesdayTable)
        break
    case .UpWednesday:
        let wednesdayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: wednesdayTable)
        break
    case .UpThursday:
        let thursdayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: thursdayTable)
        break
    case .UpFriday:
        let fridayTable = self
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: fridayTable)
        break
    case .downMonday:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: 16)
        break
    case .downTuesday:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: 17)
        break
    case .downWednesday:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: 18)
        break
    case .downThursday:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: 19)
        break
    case .downFriday:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTeacherLessons", sender: 20)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@IBOutlet weak var subjectField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var roomField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var timeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var groupField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var captainField: UITextField!

var defaultSub = UserDefaults.standard
var defaultRoom = UserDefaults.standard
var defaultTime = UserDefaults.standard
var defaultGroup = UserDefaults.standard
var defaultEmail = UserDefaults.standard
var defaultCaptain = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if let sub = defaultSub.string(forKey: "subjectField"){
        subjectField.text = sub
    }
    if let room = defaultRoom.string(forKey: "roomField"){
        roomField.text = room
    }
    if let time = defaultTime.string(forKey: "timeField"){
        timeField.text = time
    }
    if let group = defaultGroup.string(forKey: "groupField"){
        groupField.text = group
    }
    if let email = defaultEmail.string(forKey: "emailField"){
        emailField.text = email
    }
    if let captain = defaultCaptain.string(forKey: "captainField"){
        captainField.text = captain
    }
    }

@IBAction func saveData(_ sender: UIButton) {
   defaultSub.set(subjectField.text, forKey: "subjectField")
   defaultRoom.set(roomField.text, forKey: "roomField")
   defaultTime.set(timeField.text, forKey: "timeField")
   defaultGroup.set(groupField.text, forKey: "groupField")
   defaultEmail.set(emailField.text, forKey: "emailField")
   defaultCaptain.set(captainField.text, forKey: "captainField")
    if true{
        self.Alert(Message: "Збережено")
    }
}

func Alert (Message: String){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Увага!", message: Message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ок", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert,animated: true,completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: В том коде, который вы написали, и так "при выборе вторника будет пустая графа". Вы же никакие данные в контроллер не передаёте, он будет пустой.

Comment: Наверное немного не правильно задал вопрос, я добавил еще 2 скрина, после выбора дня недели будут кнопки с 1,2,3,4 парой, а далее уже внутри преподователь заполняет данные, мне нужно соответственно на днях недели сделать что-бы это были разные данные в каждом дне недели

Comment: Тут и так везде и всегда создаются новые контроллеры, и все данные нужно вводить заново. В чём именно проблема? У вас и без того "разные данные в каждом дне недели" – потому что кода сохранения этих данных вы не предоставили. Если данные не сохраняются, они останутся пустыми.

Comment: Добавил свой код для сохранения, проблема в том, что я введу эти данные допустим в понедельник, и они же будут отображаться во вторнике

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас все данные будут отображаться одни и те же, потому что UserDefaults – это синглтон. Данные нужно хранить более совершенным образом, поскольку UserDefaults предоставляет лишь возможность хранить пары ключ-значение ( у вас данные куда сложнее). Вот самые распространённые хранилища для iOS:

- SQLite
- Core Data
- Realm

Также можно не хранить данные локально, а скачивать их с сервера. Для этого можно использовать Parse, Google Firebase или же написать бэкенд самому (можно даже на Swift – для этого есть Vapor, Perfect, Kitura и другие фреймворки).

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не используй сегвей.
 Это очень плохая практика. 
Всегда используй переход кодом.
(Почему так?)
-Потому что при построении более сложных интерфейсов, одна и та же кнопка может осуществлять(или)не осуществлять переход на множество контроллеров.

```objective-c
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```